# What does "type domain" and "real type" mean?

Tags: c, types, language-lawyer, c11

Quoted from N1570:

> 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
>   conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
>   determine a common **real type** for the operands and result. For the
>   specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of
>   **type domain**, to a type whose corresponding **real type** is the common real type. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common
>   **real type** is also the corresponding **real type** of the result, whose **type domain** is the **type domain** of the operands if they
>   are the same, and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the usual
>   arithmetic conversions:
>
> - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double, the other operand is converted, without change of **type
>     domain**, to a type whose corresponding **real type** is long double.
> - Otherwise, ......

What is "type domain" and "real type"? I've search the document, but no definition is found.

Comment: Type domain is integer, float, structure, or union?

Comment: RTFineM: 6.2.5p18. A simple text search …

Comment: @Olaf `18 Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types. Each arithmetic type belongs to one type domain: the real type domain comprises the real types, the complex type domain comprises the complex types.`, but this doesn't define "type domain" explicitly.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Can you provide a reference?

Comment: And `real types` is explained in the previous paragraph. The standard has an index at the end btw.

Comment: Also [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/ctypes.pdf) is a nice graph about C11 types.

Comment: @cremno OK I got it: real type = type char + the signed and unsigned integer types + float + double + long double.

Comment: The term "real" is used in its mathematical sense.  Among the arithmetic types, the "real" types are the alternative to the "complex" types.  Saying it that way is not intended to suggest that the complex types are in any way more standard or conventional than the real types, however.  They are equally defined by the language standard, and the real types are far, *far* more used.

Comment: Read the paragraph I referenced in context of your question. This is about "Real" vs. "Complex" numbers and how to convert between them, including from one domain (real or complex) to the other.

Comment: Speaking of C11, it is no longer mandatory for a compiler to support the complex type library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

6.2.5 Types of N1570 says the following:

> Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types. Each arithmetic type belongs to one **type domain**: the **real type domain** comprises the **real types**, the **complex type domain** comprises the **complex
>   types**.

Then further:

> There   are   three
>   **real**   floating   **types**
>   ,   designated   as
>   `float`
>   ,
>   `double`
>   ,   and
>   `long
>   double`.
>   42)
>   The  set  of  values  of  the  type
>   `float`
>   is  a  subset  of  the  set  of  values  of  the
>   type
>   double
>   ; the set of values of the type
>   double
>   is a subset of the set of values of the
>   type
>   long double

and

> There   are   three
>   complex   types,   designated   as
>   `float  _Complex`
>   ,
>   `double _Complex`,  and
>   `long  double  _Complex`.

(do note that the standard does not say anything about complex integer types, so all integer types defined in the standard belong to the real type domain).

Thus it is clear that the domain refers to the mathematical concepts of [**real** numbers ℝ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) and [complex numbers ℂ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

---

Basically what the excerpt in your question says is that if you for example add a real number with imaginary number or a complex number, the result is also a complex number; and also that the operands are promoted to the width of the largest operand before the operation.